# Swift 3 Convert Double to String

Tags: swift3

I keep getting this error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'.

I am trying to display some core data values and this one is a double. Ive tried to work around it the same way I had to do to store the values when converting it.

Heres the code that gives me the error:

```
func displayStats() {
    // display other attributes if they have values
    if let servingSize  = mealstats.serving {
        servingsLabel.text = servingSize
}
```

Comment: So `mealstats.serving` is a Double? in that case you could just do `servingsLabel.text = "\(mealstats.serving)"`

Comment: Very probably you want to use a `NSNumberFormatter` to format the number correctly into a string.

Comment: String(mealstats.serving)

Comment: Yes its a Double. I thought about trying the NSNumberFormatter but, wasn't sure how that will work. I will try that tomorrow morning when I get free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mealstats.serving is most probably of type "Double" and not "Double?"
Since it is not optional it cannot be unwrapped. The right way to use it would be

```
func displayStats() {
    // display other attributes if they have values
    servingsLabel.text = "\(mealstats.serving)"
}
```

Comment: This may produce the wrong result as it does not respect regional settings.